# Help me get my robotic car to work?

Tags: arduino-nano, motor, hardware, hc-05, l298n

So I recently followed a tutorial on youtube and I've assembled the car and connected all the wires.

What I've done:
[Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPDvZ.jpg)

Now in the video, when the guy connects all the wires, the wheels constantly turn while in mine they're completely still. Is this a problem? Is it an indicator of some connection issue or something else?

For context, here is the schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Add your code, and use the minimal code that should be able to spin the wheels (preferably test yourself). Also recheck all connections (the picture in the link is hard to 'analyze' ).

Comment: `when the guy connects all the wires, the wheels constantly turn` ... that sounds like his car is not working correctly ... the wheels should not turn until commanded to turn

Answer (score 1):

The ENA/ENB (enable A/B) pins have to be at HIGH level (either hardwired or set by an mcu). There exist lots of different driver boards (mostly based on the same ICs) which sometimes don't provide this enable pin, but they are "enabled" by default. You didn't tell us which board you use, but you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your motor-driver board but here are several things to check out, based on your schematic:

- The motor driver board has two enable pins. Neither of them is connected. It would make sense that these pins turn the two motors on and off.
- The pin marked 12v is connected to +5v.
- The linked photo of your car shows two 9v "Transistor" batteries. This kind of battery in particular is not capable of supplying much current and they most likely unable to turn the motors.

Answer (score 0):

Check These:

As you have used two power source you must **common ground them**.

**You must check L298N motor drivers enable pins.As you have only 4 wire to motor driver from arduino.So you must give EnA and EnB pin 5v/HIGH or  You can give it (0-255) pwm value from arduino to control the speed of your motor **

If wiring is ok then you must go throw you Sketch.